# How to get left assoc operators with scala combinators?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I've tried

```
/* inside RegexParser class */
def exp : Parser[Exp] = 
  term~addop_chain ^^ {case l~ThenAdd(optype,r) => AritOp(l,optype,r)}

def addop_chain : Parser[Exp] = 
  ("+"|"-")~term~addop_chain ^^ {case sym~term~ThenAdd(optype,r) => ThenAdd(sym, AritOp(term,optype,r)) }  |
  ("+"|"-")~term ^^ {case sym~term => ThenAdd(sym, term)}

def term = /* right now, only int literal. code unrelevant */

/* Case classes for storing: */
case class ThenAdd(sym: String, r: Exp)
case class AritOp(l: Exp, sym: String, r: Exp)
```

Which works!, but is right-assoc (not left-assoc), e.g. 5+(3-2), which is not what I want.

What I want is something like:

```
5+3-2
```

should become

```
AritOp(AritOp(5,+,3), -, 2)
```

(left assoc) But this feels almost impossible without (proper?) left recursion. What can I do?

(constriant: I can't use `rep, repsep, opt` (I'm doing an assignment, so the grammer should be as BNF as possible (ie. **not EBNF**)))

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the parsers that need to be left-assoc with `chainl1` from http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers?

Comment: Interesting. But I can't find a proper example of how to use it anywhere. Not sure how to understand `A parser generator that, roughly, generalises the rep1sep generator so that q, which parses the separator, produces a left-associative function that combines the elements it separates.` without any examples :(

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/docs/examples/parsing/ArithmeticParser.scala#L44 - very similar to what you're trying to do.