# Parser combinator grammar not yielding correct associativity

Tags: scala, parsing, bnf, parser-combinators, associativity

I am working on a simple expression parser, however given the following parser combinator declarations below, I can't seem to pass my tests and a right associative tree keeps on popping up.

```
def EXPR:Parser[E] = FACTOR ~ rep(SUM|MINUS) ^^ {case a~b => (a /: b)((acc,f) => f(acc))}
def SUM:Parser[E => E] = "+" ~ EXPR ^^ {case "+" ~ b => Sum(_, b)}
def MINUS:Parser[E => E] = "-" ~ EXPR ^^ {case "-" ~ b => Diff(_, b)}
```

I've been debugging hours for this. I hope someone can help me figure it out it's not coming out right.

"5-4-3" would yield a tree that evaluates to 4 instead of the expected -2.

What is wrong with the grammar above?

Comment: I found [How to get left assoc operators with scala combinators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15729412/1243762) which lead me to [scala.util.parsing.combinator](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers) take a look at chainl1.

Comment: See also https://blog.jcoglan.com/2017/07/07/precedence-and-associativity-in-recursive-descent/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems using "+" ~ EXPR made the answer incorrect. It should have been FACTOR instead.

Answer (score 4):

I don't work with Scala but do work with F# parser combinators and also needed associativity with infix operators. While I am sure you can do 5-4 or 2+3, the problem comes in with a sequence of two or more such operators of the same precedence and operator, i.e. 5-4-2 or 2+3+5. The problem won't show up with addition as (2+3)+5 = 2+(3+5) but (5-4)-2 <> 5-(4-2) as you know.

See: [Monadic Parser Combinators](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~gmh/monparsing.pdf) 4.3 Repetition with meaningful separators. Note: The separators are the operators such as "+" and "*" and not whitespace or commas.

See: [Functional Parsers](http://roman-dushkin.narod.ru/files/fp__jeroen_fokker_001.pdf) Look for the chainl and chainr parsers in section 7. More parser combinators.

> For example, an arithmetical expressions, where the operators that
>   separate the subexpressions have to be part of the parse tree. For
>   this case we will develop the functions chainr and chainl. These
>   functions expect that the parser for the separators yields a function
>   (!);
>
> The function f should operate on an element and a list of tuples, each
>   containing an operator and an element. For example, f(e0; [(1; e1);
>   (2; e2); (3; e3)]) should return ((eo 1 e1) 2 e2) 3 e3. You may
>   recognize a version of foldl in this (albeit an uncurried one), where
>   a tuple (; y) from the list and intermediate result x are combined
>   applying x  y.

You need a `fold function` in the semantic parser, i.e. the part that converts the tokens from the syntactic parser into the output of the parser. In your code I believe it is this part.

```
{case a~b => (a /: b)((acc,f) => f(acc))}
```

Sorry I can't do better as I don't use Scala.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/docs/examples/parsing/ArithmeticParser.scala#L44) it is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

```
"-" ~ EXPR ^^ {case "-" ~ b => Diff(_, b)}
```

for 5-4-3, it expands to

```
Diff(5, 4-3)
```

which is

```
Diff(5, Diff(4, 3))
```

however, what you need is:

```
Diff(Diff(5, 4), 3))

// for 5 + 4 - 3 it should be

Diff(Sum(5, 4), 3)
```

you need to involve stack.